# Cannot access most of admin tools in Win10 from admin account

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I use Win10 pro on my personal desktop (eg not part of a domain) and recently started to get weird issues that I cannot open device manager, cannot edit environment variables, or group policy and many others. I don't recall that I did anything weird in my system, the only "unusual" change I made is added myself to "Create symbolic links" permissions in group policies:

Run `secpol.msc`. In the `Local Policies`, go to `Security Settings` > `Local Policies` > `User Rights Assignment`. In the list, find the Create symbolic links item. Add my own account to the list:
[image]

In all cases I get error message box with this message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.

That's what I get for device manager:

[image]
[image]

"Edit group policy":

[image]
[image]

If I try to edit environment variables:

[image]
[image]

There is a [relevant article on msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2669244/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you), but when I tried to check if my user is part of Administrator group I got this as well:

[image]
[image]

If I try to run regedit, however, I get UAC prompt and I can run regedit with no issues. Same for mmc.exe (I can run it from \Windows\system32 and get an UAC prompt). This makes, no sense, but my Win10 is complete train-wreck now. I also now, that if restart everything will be OK. Any ideas what's going on?

**Edit:** If I r-click `Windows Explorer` in task manager, and do "Restart" then after explorer restart the problem gets fixed.

[image]

Comment: Use "netplwiz" from the Run box to access user account management (you can try "lusrmgr.msc", but you might be restricted from opening that one too), and check the real status of your account. Push come to shove, boot in Safe Mode and see if things work better. If they do, it could mean you've got malware on your PC. Run an antivirus scan in Safe Mode is possible, or a boot scan with Avast... if you can install it...

Comment: Have you tried __Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth__ or __SFC /ScanNow__ ?

Comment: I know this probably does not mean much but the two numbers, stated above are: ::{Control Panel}\0\::{Device Manager}. I would do a complete cleanup (1) Run CHKDSK /F from a command prompt, then Restart the computer. (2) DISM as stated in my previous comment. (3) Run SFC /ScanNow (4) Create a shortcut to Disk Cleanup wizard and __Run as Administrator__ %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe and check all boxes especially Windows Update cleanup. Restart after it finishes (5) Defrag the hard disk(s). Then Restart again.

Comment: At this point, I would attempt an in-place upgrade to the same version you are currently running, in order to fix the problems you describe.  You will have to describe exactly what you did when you indicated, "added myself to "Create symbolic links" permissions in group policies.", as currently written that part of your question is not clear.

Comment: Added info regarding `Create symbolic links`

Comment: @vssher Both are OK.

Comment: @Pavel P I haven't been here for a few days, sorry about the delay, have you fixed your issues? It sounds like maybe you have some sort of malware/virus or maybe even a rootkit. If you have not done so, I would try a complete scan with Defender, and also, maybe a 3-rd party antivirus software with a good reputation. I hope you have fixed your issue.

Comment: Unlikely that I have a rootkit/virus (RootkitRevealer by the way can be used to try to detect it). I had LTSC variant of win10 to avoid doing frequent updates, I switched to regular win10 pro and don't have that issue anymore. Not sure what the issue was in the first place, other than some sort of bug in windows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on restarting Windows Explorer! It fixed the problem for me.